# In Landscape swiping not working in Windows Phone 8 app programatically

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm beginner to windows phone development and i done swiping the images in carousel view in portrait orientation and i tried for landscape orintation which is not done succesfully.please any one help me to resolve this issue.

```
TouchPoint _first;

private List<TList> _pivotList;

public Pivot()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += pivot_Loaded;
    Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
}







private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)

{ 

TouchPoint mainTouch = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(null);

if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Down)

    _first = mainTouch;

else if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Up)

{
    var xDelta = mainTouch.Position.X - _first.Position.X;

    var yDelta = Math.Abs(mainTouch.Position.Y - _first.Position.Y);

    if (yDelta > Math.Abs(xDelta))

        return;

    if (Math.Abs(xDelta - 0) > 10)

    {

        var currentIndex = pivotList.SelectedIndex;

        int noOfPivotItems = pivotList.Items.Count;


        currentIndex = (xDelta < 0) ?

            ++currentIndex % noOfPivotItems :
            (--currentIndex + noOfPivotItems) % noOfPivotItems;
        pivotList.SelectedIndex = currentIndex;

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is code for DisplayOrientations .

```
public Pivot()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += pivot_Loaded;
            this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
            Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped;


        }
```

Comment: sorry it is not worked do you have any other idea if i give xdelta ,ydelta functions properly to the landscape it will works fine because i tried like this for swiping left and right incrementing.

Comment: if (Math.Abs(yDelta - 0) > 10)

    {

        var currentIndex = pivotList.SelectedIndex;

        int noOfPivotItems = pivotList.Items.Count;


        currentIndex = (yDelta < 0) ?

            ++currentIndex % noOfPivotItems :
            (--currentIndex + noOfPivotItems) % noOfPivotItems;
        pivotList.SelectedIndex = currentIndex;

    }